# Is this overwriting the max function in python?

Tags: python

Define a function max() that takes two numbers as arguments and returns the largest of them. Use the if-then-else construct available in Python. (It is true that Python has the max() function built in, but writing it yourself is nevertheless a good exercise.)

```
def max(a,b):
    if a > b:
        print (a)
    elif a < b:
        print (b)
    elif (a==b):
        return (a)
    print ("function executed")
    print (max(4,5))

max(1,2)
```

The output of this function is,

```
2
function executed
None
5
function executed
None
```

Comment: You have not yet met the specification - your function doesn't return anything. Also, it fails in the case `a == b`.

Comment: And how do you define the *elegant*?

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I tried return, but it doesn't print anything to the console.

Comment: Its not supposed to print anything, its just supposed to return the largest of two.

Comment: @user3421311 You should not edit your question so much that it becomes an entirely different question. Either ask a new question, or request a clarification to the answer in the comments.

Comment: I reverted the question to its original state. To answer your follow-up question: When `a == b`, then `a > b` is false, so whatever happens in the `else` part is used for both `a < b` **and** `a == b`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/1903116), like this

```
def max(a, b):
    return a if a > b else b
```

Since the function just returns the biggest value, you might want to print the result yourself, like this

```
print max(1, 2)
```

Or if you are using Python 3.x, then `print` is not a statement, but a function. So, it has to be called like this

```
print(max(1, 2))
```